# Open local file with IE using batch (.bat)

Tags: batch-file

```
start iexplore test.html
exit
```

That attempts to open http://test.html, i just want it to open the local file test.html, which resides in the same directory as the batch file.

```
start firefox test.html
exit
```

Works as expected, by opening the local file in firefox... is there anyway to force the batch to open the local file relative the batch file?

Using `start iexplore file://%CD%\test.html` as suggested by Dave works, but not on thumdrives, which is what I need it for.

Comment: Does it have to launch in IE? Is the user's default browser acceptable? (Your title says IE, but the text says `in firefox... is there anyway to force the batch to open the local file relative the batch file?`.)

Comment: @KenWhite It does have to be IE.

Comment: OK. I just checked in a WinXP VM, and omitting the program name works fine to start IE if it's the default browser (as well as FF) with just `start test.html`, even if the HTML file is on a thumbdrive. Of course, this just starts the default browser, so I wanted to clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to work for both local and USB drives:

`START iexplore %~dps0test.html`

Comment: Make sure it works with names/paths containing special characters (like space, `&` and some others). Most likely you'll need to enclose `%~dps0test.html` in double quotes.

Answer (score 4):

To open a file you would normally pass in;

`start iexplore file://c:\test\test.html`

So you would need some way to know your current path. You can do this with the [`%CD%` pseudo variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/28/362565.aspx).

`start iexplore file://%CD%\test.html`

Comment: When opening from a thumbdrive I get `Cannot find file:///E://test.html`

Comment: @kylex Is that because you have an extra forward slash at the start? `start iexplore file://E:\test.html`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "file://%~dp0test.html"
```

If

- You do not want to assume that IE is the default browser
- You would like to show the full filename in the address bar